# How do I send keystrokes to Firefox using Test::WWW::Selenium?

Tags: javascript, perl, selenium

I have tried:

```
$sel->type_keys_ok("//fieldset[2]/input", "KEYS");
```

No results. Nothing changed.

Also tried:

```
$sel->send_keys_ok("//fieldset[2]/input", "KEYS");
```

Not implemented.

Tried also:

```
my $res = $sel->get_eval('
   function simulateKeyEvent(character) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
   (evt.initKeyEvent || evt.initKeyboardEvent)("keypress", true, true, window,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, character.charCodeAt(0)) 
   var canceled = !body.dispatchEvent(evt);
   if(canceled) {
   // A handler called preventDefault
   alert("canceled");
    } else {
   // None of the handlers called preventDefault
     alert("not canceled");
   }
   };
   simulateKeyEvent("K");' );
```

Then I got this ERROR: 'initKeyEvent' called on an object that does not implement interface KeyboardEvent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

version 1:

```
my $element = $sel->find_element("//input[\@name='q']");
$element->send_keys("KEYS");
$element->submit();
```

version 2 using WDKeys:

```
use Selenium::Remote::WDKeys;

my $element = $sel->find_element("//input[\@name='q']");
$element->send_keys("KEYS");
$sel->send_keys_to_active_element(KEYS->{'enter'});
```

for more information look at [CPAN Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver)